# Chi-Squared Probability Function in C++

Tags: c++, statistics, chi-squared

The following code of mine computes the confidence interval using Chi-square's 'quantile' and probability function from Boost.

I am trying to implement this function as to avoid dependency to Boost. Is there any resource where can I find such implementation?

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

using namespace std;     
using boost::math::chi_squared; 
using boost::math::quantile;

vector <double> ConfidenceInterval(double x) {
    vector <double> ConfInts; 

    // x is an estimated value in which
    // we want to derive the confidence interval.

    chi_squared distl(2);     
    chi_squared distu((x+1)*2);

    double alpha = 0.90;      

    double lower_limit = 0;   

    if (x != 0) {
        chi_squared distl(x*2);   
        lower_limit = (quantile(distl,((1-alpha)/2)))/2;
    }

    double upper_limit = (quantile(distu,1-((1-alpha)/2)))/2;

    ConfInts.push_back(lower_limit);
    ConfInts.push_back(upper_limit);

    return ConfInts;         
}
```

Comment: [How to Calculate the Chi-Squared P-Value](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432194/How-to-Calculate-the-Chi-Squared-P-Value) on Code Project. It came a couple of years after you asked the question, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if the method on the link works actually. I come to copy-paste it and I'm getting quite weird values with it (eg. Dof=1, Cv=51).

Comment: * It gace me an error with the approximate gamma solution, it is OK with tgamma (doble checked in R language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for source code you can copy/paste, here are some links:

- [AlgLib](http://www.alglib.net/specialfunctions/distributions/chisquare.php)
- [Koders](http://www.koders.com/default.aspx?s=c%2B%2B+chi-square)

YMMV...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Gnu Scientific library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/).  Or look in [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/).  There's also a Java version in [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html), which should be straightforward to translate.

Comment: @Charlie: my intention is to be independent from library. GSL code has many dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to implement this function as to avoid dependency to Boost.

Another option is to ***reduce*** Boost dependencies, but not ***avoid*** them. If you reduce the dependency, you might be able to use a `Boost` folder with say, 200 or 300 source files rather than the entire 1+ GB of material. (Yes, 200 or 300 can be accurate - its what I ended up with when copying out `shared_ptr`).

To reduce the dependency, use [`bcp` (boost copy)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) to copy out just the files needed for `chi_squared.hpp`. The bad thing is, you usually have to build `bcp` from sources because its not distributed in the ZIPs or TARBALLs.

To find instructions on building `bcp`, see [How to checkout latest stable Boost (not development or bleeding edge)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17777694)