# generate random number using chi square distribution c++

Tags: c++, boost, random

I need to generate random numbers representing user activities using chi square distribution in (boost) tr1 c++. Any example or help on how would I start?

---

I tried the following code:

```
int main (){
    std::tr1::mt19937 eng; // a core engine class 
                           //mt19937 is a very fast random number generator algorithm 
    eng.seed(time(0));   //each engine has a seed method 

    //file to store seed 
    std::tr1::chi_squared_distribution<double> chdist(5.0); 
    cout<<endl<<"CHIDIST"<<endl<<"================"<<endl; 

    for (int i = 0; i<50; ++i) 
    { 
         Act.push_back(chdist(eng)*0.1); 
         int rounded = ((int)(chdist(eng) * 100 + .5) / 100.0);         
         Act.push_back(rounded*0.1); cout<<Act[i]<< endl; 
    }

     return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Another related post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795972/homebrew-chi-squared-probability-function-in-c

Comment: I tried the following code: int main (){std::tr1::mt19937 eng;  // a core engine class //mt19937 is a very fast random number generator algorithm
    eng.seed(time(0)); //each engine has a seed method
    //file to store seed
 
 std::tr1::chi_squared_distribution<double> chdist(5.0);
    cout<<endl<<"CHIDIST"<<endl<<"================"<<endl;
  
  for (int i = 0; i<50; ++i)
  {
  Act.push_back(chdist(eng)*0.1);
  int rounded = ((int)(chdist(eng) * 100 + .5) / 100.0); 
  Act.push_back(rounded*0.1);
  cout<<Act[i]<< endl;
  } return 0;

}

Comment: You should include your code as a question edit, not a comment.  Use the code icon for formatting.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia:

> If Z1, ..., Zk are independent, standard normal random variables, then
>   the sum of their squares is distributed according to the chi-squared
>   distribution

so you may want to generate k standard normal variables and calculate their sum squared.

Comment: I need to implement the chi-square distribution in c++ to generate random user activities.

Comment: There are many ways to generate normally distributed variables (check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325472/generate-random-numbers-following-a-normal-distribution-in-c-c). After that you can easily generate chi-square distribution by calculating sum of their squares.