# How to checkout latest stable Boost (not development or bleeding edge)?

Tags: svn, boost, svn-checkout

According to [Boost Subversion Repository](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/BoostSubversion), I can checkout Boost's bleeding edge development with `svn co  http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk boost-trunk`.

I'm interested in checking out the latest stable version because I need [`bcp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) (`bcp` is not part of the Boost downloads). I believe the latest version of Boost is Version 1.55.0, but there's no "XXX_1_55" in `trunk`, `tags` or `branches` in the repository (where XXX would presumably be something, like "release").

How do I checkout the latest stable Boost?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the releases are found under `tags/releases` not `trunk`.  You could do `svn list http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/tags/release` to verify the release you are interested is there.

This is described at [Development and Release Practices](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/ImprovingPractices), where it indicates the URLs for final releases are in the form http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/tags/releases/xxx, where xxx is a revision like 1_54_0.

The checkout command would be similar to:

```
$ svn co http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/tags/release/Boost_1_55_0
```